# linux command find and its placeholder {} in multiline commands

Tags: bash, sh

I struggle with bash and the command find and its placeholder `{}` when using `-execdir` and the multiline escaping with `"""` for easy reading.

I want to iterate the folder `$SOURCE` and create an tar archiv of each folder at the folder `$TARGET` if this tar doesn't exist.

I tried many variants of escaping `{}` but I was not able to save the current folder in a variable. I would like to know how this placeholder works and how I could save its value to a variable in a multiline command.

### One liner is working

```
find "$SOURCE" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir sh -c 'DIR="{}";echo $DIR' \;
```

returns

```
./2007_10_03 Event1
./2007_10_12 Event2
```

### But not as a multiline command with sh and `-c`

```
find "$SOURCE" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
  -execdir sh -c """

DIR="{}"
echo $DIR

""" \;
```

return

```
sh: line 2: Event1: command not found
sh: line 2: Event2: command not found
```

Comment: What you're asking for is both not standard mandated functionality (so not all copies of find support it) and extremely insecure. Don't **ever** substitute data into a position where it'll be parsed as code; that's where injection vulnerabilities come from.

Comment: To expand on what I was saying about portability: The POSIX standard only requires `{}` to be substituted when it's a separate argument on its own, not a substring of a larger argument.

Comment: `multiline escaping with """` There is no such thing. There is no 'multiline escaping with """' in Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
find "${SOURCE:?}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '
    dir="$1"
    echo "$dir"
' sh {} \;
```

This is most readable and [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976880/linux-command-find-and-its-placeholder-in-multiline-commands/74976923#comment132313270_74976923) than using `{}`

`${SOURCE:?}` is a special *parameter expansion* that test if the variable exists. If not, `find` will not be executed, and you will have an error like:

```
bash: SOURCE: parameter null or not set
```

Comment: Not just more readable but more secure as well. But think about using a loop over arguments and `{} +` so we don't run one shell per file found unnecessarily.